# How to configure auditd to collect logs from /proc kernel file directory

Tags: logging, linux-kernel, auditd, splunk, proc

I've been looking for this for about 3 days now and have come up empty-handed. I am looking for a way to build a threat alert for Linux-based credential dumping in Splunk.

To do this I need to be able to monitor the `/proc` directory. I found audit and auditd (audit deamon) but I don't know how to actually configure auditd to monitor the `/proc`. If I could do this I could then connect audit.log to Splunk.

I want to at least monitor:

```
/proc/<PID>/maps
/proc/<PID>/mem
/proc/<PID>/cmdline
```

But ideally I want to monitor everything in `/proc`.

Has anyone here ever done this? If so I would really appreciate some help.

Additionally: I found klogd (kernel log deamon), syslogd and a ps and top combination but I don't know how to configure that to `/proc` either or if that is even what I need.

Any advice is appreciated!

I am of course open to other methods and ideas.

Comment: You cross posted this to UNIX StackExchange. Please don't, close one of them.

Answer (score -1):

A couple of options out there, for one there is Filebeat + Graylog (see writeup at https://www.graylog.org/post/back-to-basics-working-with-linux-audit-daemon-log-file) and you can also do Linux Audit logging with NXLog (see https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide/linux-audit.html)